# Adding creating a mixin and using it keystonejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I am trying to create a jade mixin for keystonejs and here is what I have come up with on my index.jade

```
extends ../layouts/default
block bodycontent
    include ../mixins/focus.jade
```

and the mixin jade file

```
mixin focus(focus)
  section#focus.focus
    div.container
          div.service-icon= focus.image
```

Here is the javascript view file

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
 Focus = keystone.list('Focus');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

        var view = new keystone.View(req, res),
            locals = res.locals;

        // Set locals
        locals.section = 'focus';

        locals.data = {

        };

        view.on('init', function(next) {

                Focus.model.find()
                    .populate('author')
                    .sort('label')
                    .limit(4)
                    .exec(function(err, fields) {
                        // do something with posts
                        locals.data.fields = fields;
                        console.log(fields);
                        next(err);
                    });
        });

        view.render('focus');

};
```

When I render the index.jade file, the focus part is missing. What am I missing ? The list model exists as I was able to save it into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike includes, you need to call mixins after declaring them. They're like functions.

See the docs here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/

Then, assuming there is some data in the `locals` that defines what to focus, you'd first include the file where the mixin is defined, then call the mixin and pass it the data to render.

I'm guessing a bit because I can't see your whole project structure but something like this is probably what you're after:

**route handler**

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Focus = keystone.list('Focus');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res),
        locals = res.locals;

    locals.section = 'focus';

    locals.data = {};

    view.on('init', function(next) {

            Focus.model.find()
                .populate('author')
                .sort('label')
                .limit(4)
                .exec(function(err, results) {
                    locals.data.results = results;
                    next(err);
                });
    });

    view.render('focus');

};
```

**mixin**

```
mixin focus(focus)
    section#focus.focus
        div.container
            div.service-icon= focus.image
```

**template**

```
extends ../layouts/default
block bodycontent
    include ../mixins/focus.jade
    each i in data.results
        +focus(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the keystone demo and was able to work it out. BTW your cms is awesome.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Thanks :D